# Client side script won't execute with ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

1. I have a user control which has an
   update panel
2. I am trying to execute a client side
   script from an async postback from a
   button inside the updatepanel
3. I am using
   `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`
   to execute the script but it never
   gets executed
4. The scriptmanager proxy is not
   inside the user control itself it is
   in the page containing the user
   control
5. Is there any way round this problem?

Script registration:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "CloseEdit", 
    "CloseEditModal();", 
    true
);
```

Thanks, Damien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation to the [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Control, Type, String, String, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx) (I assume you use this overload) says:

> Startup script blocks that are
>   registered by using this method are
>   sent to the page only when the control
>   that is registering the block is
>   inside an `UpdatePanel` control that is
>   being updated.

I assume you call the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method from your user control (*which has an update panel* as you said). This means the first parameter of the method *is not inside an `UpdatePanel` control that is being updated*, so the script block is not registered. So changing your script registraction to:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    btnUpdate, 
    btnUpdate.GetType(), 
    "CloseEdit", 
    "CloseEditModal();", 
    true
);
```

should solve your problem. `btnUpdate` here is the button inside you `UpdatePanel` that caused the postback (you mention this in paragraph 2).

Comment: Thank you Alex. Your reply was very helpful with all the explanation and links.